# React Native styling not showing using style.container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I am learning React Native and applying some simple styling to a `View`. But the styling is not showing up at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Hello </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
    container: {
        backgrounColor: '#ddd',
        color: 'red',
        paddingTop: 14
    }
}
```

If I change it to `<View style={{backgroundColor: '#ddd', color: 'red', paddingTop: 14}}>` it would work, but why won't the first approach work?

I am using:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and 
react-native: 0.57.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use StyleSheet to create JavaScript styles in react-native

Import StyleSheet from react-native and change your variable style to:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgrounColor: '#ddd',
        color: 'red',
        paddingTop: 14
    }
});
```

Comment: since which version of react-native do I have to do this? Because previously it used to work

Comment: I am not entirely sure when that changed as I have used it since i started using react native. Did my answer solve your initial question?